# Why so many giant pits in the structures of the starwars universe?

Tags: star-wars

I just noticed there are lots of really big pits in the starwars universe, some examples are:

[image]
[image]
[image]
Is there a reason?

Comment: They make for a good defense against force users. If I lived in a world full of Jedi and Sith, I'd consider having a few around myself.

Comment: So you can kick someone in and yell "THIS! IS! SPARTAAA!".

Comment: @Peter - And then wait a long time so you can sue for copyright infringement?